# Union of multiple objects based on key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

What is the best way to merge all objects in my array to one and addition all value with the same key?
I tried to achieve this in es6 with the spread operator, but I have no success so far...

```
const array = [{
    on: 1,
    off: 1,
    alarm: 1,
},{
    on: 1,
    off: 1,
    alarm: 1,
},{
    on: 1,
    off: 1,
    alarm: 1,
}];

const output = [{
    on: 3,
    off: 3,
    alarm: 3,
}];
```

Comment: Shouldn't `output` be a simple Object instead of an Array? If not, do we agree that it should only contain a single element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way, using the spread operator as you suggested:

```js
const array = [
  { on: 1, off: 1, alarm: 1 },
  { on: 1, off: 1, alarm: 1 },
  { on: 1, off: 1, alarm: 1 }
];

const output = array.reduce((res, o) => ({
  ...res,
  ...Object.fromEntries(
       Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [k, v + (res[k] || 0)])
     )
}), {});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the array, iterate each object entries with `Array.forEach()`, and assign / add to the respective key on the accumulator (`acc`):

```js
const array = [{"on":1,"off":1,"alarm":1},{"on":2,"off":2,"alarm":2},{"on":3,"off":3,"alarm":3}];

const result = array.reduce((acc, o) => {
  Object.entries(o).
    forEach(([k, v]) => acc[k] = (acc[k] ?? 0) + v)
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is my two-pennies-worth:

```js
const arr = [{ on: 1, off: 1, alarm: 1},
  {on: 1,off: 1,alarm: 1},
  {on: 1,off: 1,alarm: 1}];

const res={};
arr.forEach(c=>Object.entries(c).forEach(([k,v])=>res[k]=(res[k] || 0) + v) )

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.reduce((acc, elem) => {
        Object.keys(elem).forEach(key => {
            if (acc[key]) {
                acc[key] += elem[key];
            } else {
                acc[key] = elem[key];
            }
        });
        return acc;
    }, {})
```

will return an object `{on: 3, off: 3, alarm: 3}`

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions appear more elegant, but this was the simplest for me to understand.

```
const array = [
 {  on: 1,  off: 1,  alarm: 1 },
 {  on: 1,  off: 1,  alarm: 1 },
 {  on: 1,  off: 1,  alarm: 1 }
];

let output = { 'on':0, 'off':0, 'alarm':0 }

array.forEach( (elem,ndx) => {        // console.log(ndx, elem) 
  output.on += elem.on;
  output.off += elem.off;
  output.alarm += elem.alarm;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(output,null,2));
```